# Best dtype for creating large arrays with numpy

Tags: python, arrays, image-processing, numpy, gdal

I am looking to store pixel values from satellite imagery into an array. I've been using

```
np.empty((image_width, image_length)
```

and it worked for smaller subsets of an image, but when using it on the entire image (3858 x 3743) the code terminates very quickly and all I get is an array of zeros.

I load the image values into the array using a loop and opening the image with gdal

```
img = gdal.Open(os.path.join(fn + "\{0}".format(fname))).ReadAsArray()
```

but when I include `print img_array` I end up with just zeros.

I have tried almost every single dtype that I could find in the numpy documentation but keep getting the same result.

Is numpy unable to load this many values or is there a way to optimize the array?

I am working with 8-bit tiff images that contain NDVI (decimal) values.

Thanks

Comment: The "best dtype" is the one that comfortably holds your data. If you've got a bunch of 8-bit pixels, `uint8` is probably the best dtype, but if you've got a bunch of 32-bit-float audio samples, it won't be very good…

Comment: @abarnert The images that I am using are 8-bit tiffs. Still returns zeros when I use uint8..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not certain what type of images you are trying to read, but in the case of radarsat-2 images you can the following:

```
dataset = gdal.Open("RADARSAT_2_CALIB:SIGMA0:" + inpath + "product.xml")
S_HH = dataset.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray()
S_VV = dataset.GetRasterBand(2).ReadAsArray()
# gets the intensity  (Intensity = re**2+imag**2), and amplitude = sqrt(Intensity)
self.image_HH_I = numpy.real(S_HH)**2+numpy.imag(S_HH)**2
self.image_VV_I = numpy.real(S_VV)**2+numpy.imag(S_VV)**2
```

But that is specifically for that type of images (in this case each image contains several bands, so i need to read in each band separately with `GetRasterBand(i)`, and than do `ReadAsArray()` If there is a specific GDAL driver for the type of images you want to read in, life gets very easy

If you give some more info on the type of images you want to read in, i can maybe help more specifically

Edit: did you try something like this ? (not sure if that will work on tiff, or how many bits the header is, hence the `something:`)

```
A=open(filename,"r")
B=numpy.fromfile(A,dtype='uint8')[something:].reshape(3858,3743)
C=B*1.0
A.close()
```

Edit: The problem is solved when using 64bit python instead of 32bit, due to memory errors at 2Gb when using the 32bit python version.

Comment: @Dzinic what is the source of your images? (edited my answer to show another thing i used before, to read in images, but not certain if for .tiff that works) my guess is you are using landsat images? in that case i guess gdal should have a driver for it

Comment: I am unsure as to where the images originated from but I know that they are at a 5 meter resolution. I am able to properly load them using gdal, but it seems that when the script takes more than 2GB of memory I receive a `MemoryError`. Not sure if this is my code or the 32 bit python that I am using.

Comment: @Dzinic definately try by using a 64bit python, with 32bit python, you always get memory error at 2Gb memory usage (are you using linux? and how much ram do you have?)

Comment: I actually tried 64 bit yesterday and it worked without a problem. The difference that 32 bits makes... Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: @Dzinic does this answer your question? or do you still have problems when working with the 64bit ?

Comment: This answered the question. If you can, edit your original answer with the 64 bit solution and I will mark it as the best answer.